# Proof that if $a$ has an inverse in $R$ then $\langle a \rangle = R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $a \in R$, I want to prove that if $a$ has an inverse in $R$ then $\langle a\rangle = R$. I know that:
$$\langle a\rangle = \{ r \cdot a  \: | \: r \in R\}$$
And I also know that $1$ is in $\langle a\rangle$, but I don't know where to go from here. Can someone help me?

Comment: For a given $x\in R$ you have that $xa^{-1}\in R$ and that $xa^{-1}\cdot a\in \langle a\rangle$

Comment: Isn't it just as simple as noting that for any $s\in R$, you have $s =(sa^{-1})a$?

Comment: $x=xa^{-1}a{}{}{}$

Comment: I assume $R$ is a commutative ring? Otherwise, your definition of $(a)$ is wrong.

Comment: @Mark how would you define it, then?

Comment: @fdez This has to be the smallest ideal containing $a$. Problem is, if $R$ is not commutative then $\{ra: r\in R\}$ might not be an ideal. In this case the best description is $\{\sum_{i=1}^n r_ias_i: n\in\mathbb{N}, r_i,s_i\in R\}$. Anyway, the statement you want to prove it true even in non commutative rings.

Comment: @JMoravitz +1 (also) but it **is** a little tacky to be that adroit

Comment: @user2661923 There is nothing special about that argument, it is the most natural thing to do. (And therefore the best possible answer here.)

Comment: @QiZhu and "best possible answer" = adroit.

Comment: @user2661923 Hm okay, I apologize then. I was under the impression that "adroit" means "very clever".

Comment: @QiZhu touche..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted in the comments : Let $r\in R$. Then, $r=(ra^{-1})a$, with $ra^{-1}\in R$, so that $r\in \langle a \rangle$. Conversely, $\langle a \rangle \subseteq R$ and thus we have equality of sets.